# Why can't I find an ActiveRecord instance by its auth token?

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

```
def current_user
  @current_user ||= User.find_by_auth_token!(cookies[:auth_token]) if cookies[:auth_token]
end
```

I've even tried this:

```
begin
  @current_user ||= User.find_by_auth_token!(cookies[:auth_token]) if cookies[:auth_token]
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound => e
  @current_user ||= nil
end
```

But it is only returning the nil value.
Please help.

Controller:

```
if params[:remember_me]
  cookies.permanent[:auth_token] = user.auth_token
else
  cookies[:auth_token] = user.auth_token
end
```

EDIT:
Model:

```
before_create :generate_token(:auth_token)
def generate_token(column)
  begin 
    self[column] = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
  end while User.exists?(column => self[column])
end
```

I think I am having a problem with `before_create`. Is the way it is written correct?

Comment: So, is `cookies[:auth_token]` set? Is there a user with a corresponding auth token? How are we supposed to debug this for you with out knowing anything about the state of your cookies, request or database?

Comment: @meagar I've added the controller part. could you look at it. Really stuck at this !

Comment: Can you print out to the logs what the value of `cookies[:auth_token]` is in your `def current_user` method just before you're 're trying to use it? Then can you verify that your database actually has a `User` record in it with the value you logged?

Answer (score 1):

This has worked for me, for those times when the browser's cookies and those saved to a user model are mis-aligned:

```
  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find_by_auth_token!(cookies[:auth_token]) if cookies[:auth_token]
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound => e
    @current_user ||= session[:current_user_id] && User.find_by_id(session[:current_user_id]) # Use find_by_id to get nil instead of an error if user doesn't exist
  end
  helper_method :current_user
```

For me the issue would arise when deleting a user that was currently signed in.  The above code stops any errors.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you canno't find that instance, because the cookie doesn't exist anymore in your web browser, there is a conflict. You should therefore clear your browser's datacache, and the problem will disapear.